# MNIST hidden layer intuitive understanding

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

For the simplest MNIST solution with 1 hidden layer, can I understand the number of hidden neurons as how many parts we divide the inputs?
For example: [784,30,10]
Can I say I divide 784 pixels into 30 small images (784/30 pixels in each image) then do the calculation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean. If you have a network that is layered like [784, 30, 10], you have 784 input neurons, 30 hidden neurons and 10 output neurons. The neurons don't know anything about 'pixels', they are just parameters. The network is basically calculating 30 values from the first input, and the output calculates 10 values from the previous 30 values.

> Can I say I divide 784 pixels into 30 small images (784/30 pixels in each image) then do the calculation?

No, as a neuron is not an image.

Comment: So my understanding here is that the hidden layer is just an abstraction of the real input, the neurons in hidden layer can also be more than input. Is it correct?

Comment: @Demon exactly! Every hidden layer is an abstraction of the real input in relation to the desired output. The neurons in a hidden layer can be any number, independent of the input/output size.